# Regional Fonts (Malayalam) not readable in LO 5.3

Tags: fonts, malayalam

Fonts from my regional language malayalam has been installed and manually copied in `local/share/fonts`, but *libre office 5.3* not detecting fonts.

Also I have notice that *libre office* and *libreoffice 5.3* both are listed in my application list.

1) *libre office* is able to read fonts but not able to type it.

2) *Libre office 5.3* not able to type or read

Please help

Comment: The `fonts-mlym` package in the Ubuntu archive provides fonts for Malayalam. Try to install that package.

Comment: libre removed and reinstalled worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to remove the files from **/tmp** folder. If it doesn't work the make a directory **.fonts** in your home folder and copy all the fonts in that folder.